# How to get cumulative sum by group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sum, partition

Here is desired result :

[image]

At ID=14, I need to reset cum value add with new `cum_value`.

SQL : (fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62f01/14)

Comment: I'm not sure to quite understand "At ID=14, I need to reset cum value add with new cum_value." could you give more details please ?

Comment: At ID value equal to 14, need to *1000) and for the next value will cumulative base on new value at ID = 14. Ex Formula in excel : IF(IDx=14,P_cum_value*1000,P_cum_value+ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not so far, but I've try with less complicated queries :

```
DECLARE @t table(
        id int
        )

INSERT  INTO @t (id)
VALUES  (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),
        (7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),
        (14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
        (20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(99);

SELECT  *
        ,SUM(id)
         OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cum_STEPID
FROM    @t
WHERE   id < 14
UNION
SELECT  *
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN id = 14 THEN 91000 ELSE id END)
         OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cum_STEPID
FROM    @t
WHERE   id >= 14
```

Comment: Thanks @Rubik, you drive me to the solution. I already update my final solution at fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62f01/14.